# Combine and split cable signals?

Tags: electrical, coaxial-cable

There are two cable signals entering the house - Spectrum's ISP+landline signal and a digital TV antenna signal. For now they are routed to two different locations. The Spectrum signal provides internet connectivity to a wireless router. My computer is connected to a port on the router. This is all good.

We're considering relocating my computer into the room that receives the digital TV signal. It would be really handy if there is some way to combine the Spectrum & antenna signals at the service entrance and then split the signal back to separate Spectrum & antenna signals in the TV room. (Spectrum signal would then go to the relocated router, antenna signal to TV.) Is it possible to combine then split signals? Or do I have to crawl around under the house and rewire stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer looks like "no", based on [this article](https://longrangesignal.com/can-you-have-cable-internet-and-an-antenna-on-the-same-cable/).  It discusses trying to have TV signal and cable internet over one wire, but the points they bring up are the same.  Some seem a little exaggerated, but the two main points are that signals can overlap, and you might cause interference on the cable line.

It looks like the first issue they bring up (overlapping signal) might be the worst for you if you are trying to use internet, cable TV, and over the air signals.  They also mention that you can possibly back-feed RF interference on the line which could disrupt service for neighbors.  To me it *seems* like there should be some kind of isolation, but maybe this is a problem in some circumstances.

Either way, this probably won't work.  If you live in a small town and only have a few broadcast channels it might work, but I wouldn't want to possibly sacrifice my internet reliability to try it.

Comment: Amongst other things, it will take less time for me to fiddle with the houses wiring than to find out whether I'd be overlapping frequencies. (An aside - the suggestion to combine signals came from my wife who had spent 3 years with the FCC in Washington. But that was in the 70s.)

Comment: Well, early AV equipment could run over the same Coax connection by emulating channel 3 or 4, so its reasonable to think there might be a way.  You have to think of coax cable as transmitting radio frequencies just like over the air.  Things can't overlap like radio stations interfering with each other. On coax, the cable company can use any frequency they want for various channels, so theres no way to know if you're going to overlap or not.